How to fallback to secondary window.location url redirect if file not found for original redirect
I am using Swiper JS to create a series of locally hosted thumbs galleries as html files. I have an index page that acts as the global location to navigate into any particular thumbs gallery. I would also like to add the functionality that if you are already inside one of the thumbs galleries (One.html) when you get to the end use the On reachEnd parameter in Swiper JS and jump to the next html in sequence. I am using javascript to get the file path of the active html file when reachEnd is activated, I then parse the file path to get the file name, increment the characters at the end of the file name, concatenate the string back together and use the window.location(newpath) action to redirect to the new url.
I have this working but the problem I cannot seem to figure out is how to handle the situation where I am either at the very first or very last html file. When the on reachEnd parameter is triggered I want to redirect back to the Index.html if the newly incremented file path cannot be found.
I was trying to use a function like this as a fallback for when the file cannot be found but the function does not catch the error and continues to try and open the failing url instead of the redirect.
example.com and fallback.com are replaced with my own concatenated paths and I have also tested directly by using file names I know exist. In both cases it dismisses the fallback redirect.
How do I enforce a redirect when the originalUrl cannot be found.
function redirectToUrl(originalUrl, fallbackUrl) {
  try {
    // Attempt to redirect to the original URL
    window.location.href = originalUrl;
  } catch (error) {
    // If an error occurs (e.g., URL not found), redirect to the fallback URL
    window.location.href = fallbackUrl;
  }
}

// Example usage:
redirectToUrl("https://example.com", "https://fallback.com");



You can find a solution to this (as the answers below do), but the issue is that this learning is good for your own local site, but it will never work outside of that niche use case. You might actually be better off not forwarding to another but loadijng the other page with JS and then replacing your current contents on the page - this would be a better experience tbh.

As a variant you can make a HEAD request to the originalUrl and check if the response status is ok. Like this:
async function redirectToUrl(originalUrl, fallbackUrl) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(originalUrl, { method: 'HEAD' });

    if (response.ok) {
      window.location.href = originalUrl;
    } else {
      window.location.href = fallbackUrl;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    window.location.href = fallbackUrl;
  }
}


Thank you for the suggest. However, I cannot seem to get the function to redirect to the originalUrl. I am manually setting originalUrl to a filename I know exists in a local file just for testing. The function always resolves to the fallbackUrl. How does the fetch work? Since these are locally hosted files and I do not have the option to use a server side language to offer up the files I need to systemically providing the file path to try and open. If it is not there it will not open, if it is it will. Is the fetch actually trying to open the file?

The result of const response = await fetch(originalUrl, { method: 'HEAD' }); is [object Response]

@fishy The result of await fetch(originalUrl, { method: 'HEAD' }); is Response, though. You just omitted the await?
